# Possible dns problem?

Tags: domain-name-system

For some reason, we are blocked from accessing our external website from within our company network.

For example. from the company network, only http://www.companyname.com works, but http://companyname.com does not work.

If I try http://www.companyname.com and http://companyname.com from home, both work properly.

Comment: What IP does http://companyname.com resolve to within your company network and is it different to www.companyname.com?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the first question, but the answer to the second question is that it is definitely different from www.companyname.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should talk to your system administrator about this as it sounds like your company is using split DNS and the internal DNS doesn't have a record for `companyname.com`.

Comment: The sys admin has added a 'www' A record to the companyname.com zone, and it makes no difference.

Comment: @oshirowanen, as www was already working the admin needs to add the appropriate record for letting you get to the site without needing www.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your active directory domain may also be companyname.com, if not then it sounds like your internal DNS server does not have the correct records for it.

Add a new A record for company.com on your internal DNS server pointing to your external website.  If company.com is your internal domain name then I would not recommend doing this.  You might look at creating a new internal only record for this, something like http://website/ which does a redirect to www.companyname.com.  Not ideal but the only solution I can think of.

Comment: I think you might be right.  We are using company.com for our active directory domain.

Comment: in that instance company.com should always resolve to one of your domain controllers.

Comment: I don't understand?  When I type http://companyname.com. I get a host refused connection error message in the browser, even though it works from my phone which is not using the network I am trying to access it from.

Comment: from a command prompt type nslookup companyname.com.  It will likely return the ip of your domain controller, rather than your website.  Active Directory doesn't know its a website, it just knows that its your internal domain name.